# Issue using grammar with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Have a minor issue when updating records in MySQL using PDO. It fails to update when I use grammar so for an example, if I use: `'` it fails me. I am using my prepare, but it's just the apostrophe that fails to work?

```
if($_POST['ourstory']) {
    foreach($_POST['ourstory'] as $id => $ourstory) {
        $sql = "UPDATE our_story SET content = '$ourstory' WHERE id = '$id'";
        $q = $db->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($id,$ourstory));
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be binding the variables, rather than adding them right into the SQL string.

Comment: ? This question mark is actually an answer.. :P

Comment: You're vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. you're using prepared statements, so you **SHOULD** be using placeholders. e.g. `... content = ? WHERE id = ?`,

Comment: `$sql = "UPDATE our_story SET content = ? WHERE id = ?";` since you are using `execute(array())`, use question mark placeholders

Comment: *Punctuation*, not grammar. You'd hope sentences do not need to be ungrammatical to be inserted into a database. Also: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: Also http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I come here for a solution, people downvote the post. Can some moderator close the post, I don't want to get banned.

Comment: You can delete it. I flagged it any I'm sure many others have also.

Comment: This is a valid question, but it has been answered in various forms before. This is just the basics of [using PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you use prepared statements.  You want to use a `?` in your query.

```
$sql = "UPDATE our_story SET content = ? WHERE id = ?";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($ourstory, $id));
```

Comment: Thank you. I not so good with English, but thank you very greatly.

Comment: You can also do `SET content=:content WHERE id=:id` and then `execute(array(':content' => $content, ':id' => $id'))`.